# Installation progress stuck at splash screen ("Started WPA supplicant.")

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 15.04

I downloaded Ubuntu 15.04 via torrent and made a bootable USB using:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

I inserted the stick into a new ASUS laptop (running free dos) and it booted successfully.

The installation progress stucks at splash screen. I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> and the last message in the output is:

```
[ OK ] Started WPA supplicant.
```

I see no errors in the output. While this looks more or less like a bug, I'm interested to know if there is a workaround/solution.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the bootable USB. Most probably I forgot to unmount the stick before ejecting it from the machine.

I repeated the `dd` process and pressed the eject icon in nautilus and then it magically worked.